# How do I insert a new meta key / value pair, but only if another meta key is present?

Tags: post-meta, sql

I need to add a new meta key and value part only on posts where another key is present (regardless of its value).

I tried to use a query to automate it, but my SQL is quite limited

Here's what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT
(SELECT meta.post_id
FROM `wp_postmeta` meta
INNER JOIN wp_posts posts ON meta.post_id = posts.id
WHERE meta.meta_key = 'existingkey'),
('newkey'),
('newvalue')
```

It returns the `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row` error.

Comment: Why are you doing this with raw SQL rather than API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to do this via raw SQL.

Make use of the WordPress core functions [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) and [`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta).
Use them like so:

```
$existing = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'existingkey', true );

if ( ! empty( $existing ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'newkey', 'newvalue' );
}
```

Done.